# Lottery Program (ArrayList)

Tags: java, arrays, file, arraylist

I'm currently working on a program that mimics a lottery and reads the following information from a `File` the file includes:

```
5
Durant Kevin
1 15 19 26 33 46
Schofield Michael
17 19 33 34 46 47
Black Joe
1 4 9 16 25 36
Elroy Jetson
17 19 34 46 47 48
Simone Raven
5 10 17 19 34 47
```

I `Scan` in the contents of the `File` and created a Ticket object to hold the name and ticket number of one person however my problem occurs when I'm trying to put that information into an `ArrayList` any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
        try
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
        ArrayList<Ticket> info = new ArrayList<Ticket>();
        int lim = scan.nextInt();

        for(int i = 0; i < lim; i++)
        {
            String name = scan.nextLine();
            String num = scan.nextLine();
            String[] tarr = num.split(" ");
            int[] arr = new int[tarr.length];

            for(int j = 0; j < tarr.length; j++)
            {
                arr[j] = Integer.parseInt(tarr[j]);
            }

            info.add(new Ticket(name, arr[]);
        }
        scan.close();
    }

    catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe)
    {
        System.out.println("Error! The file was not found!");
    }

}

public class Ticket
{
    public String name;
    public int[] tarray;

    public Ticket(String name, int[] tarray)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.tarray = tarray;
    }
}
```

Comment: For future reference, it would be better if you also had included your stack trace in your question.

Comment: No need for `FileInputStream`. [`new Scanner(file)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.File%29) will do it. Though you might want to move it to the `try` statement, i.e. use try-with-resources.

Answer (score 3):

Your original code actually looks very clean and I only found the following problem:

```
info.add(new Ticket(name, arr[]);
```

This is not valid Java syntax for passing a variable AFAIK.  If you want to pass the `arr` of numbers to the constructor of the `Ticket` class you should be doing this instead:

```
info.add(new Ticket(name, arr));
```

**Update:**

I have tested your code locally using IntelliJ, and the only other potential problem I found was in the following line:

```
int lim = scan.nextInt();
```

Calling `Scanner.nextInt()` does *not* update the cursor to the next line.  This means that when you attempt to read the second line you will still be on the first one.  A quick fix for this is to change to the following code:

```
int lim = scan.nextInt();   // read in number of people
scan.nextLine();            // advance to second line of input file
```

Comment: "tested [...] using IntelliJ". Yeah, there's a novel concept. People *testing* their code before asking others to fix it for them.

Comment: @Andreas I agree completely.  If he had even taken the time to cut and paste the stack trace, he probably would have figured it out himself.

Comment: @Beginner Please review the answers given.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is in the constructor of the Ticket class.

You cannot just set one array equal to another. You can, however, clone it:

```
this.tarray = tarray.clone();
```

Comment: This should be nothing wrong with doing this in the `Ticket` constructor.